# :valid css shows even when $valid: false

Tags: html, angularjs, css

so here is my code, I use a custom directive to determine if the two passwords match, here is my html

```
<!-- confirm password -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-centered">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12 inputLabels">
                <b>Confirm Password:</b>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
                <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" ng-model="boardingData.confirmPassword" class="form-control" required compare-to="boardingData.password">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the directive to determine if the passwords match

```
app.directive('compareTo', function() {
return {
    require: "ngModel",
    scope: {
        otherModelValue: "=compareTo"
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {

        ngModel.$validators.compareTo = function(modelValue) {
            return modelValue == scope.otherModelValue;
        };

        scope.$watch("otherModelValue", function() {
            ngModel.$validate();
        });
    }
};
```

});

finally the css

```
input:valid {box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgb(97, 240, 59);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because :valid is a pseudo-class specific to if the content of an input matches the [type] attribute.  As you can see on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:valid .  What you are instead wanting is the class ng-valid as seen here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form .

Let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: perfect answer! was pulling my hair out because I wasn't sure how the :valid was determining when to trigger. Thanks so much

Comment: No problem, that's what the site is for! :)